# Sharing a list of image Uri through intent giving file format not supported error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, whatsapp, intentfilter

I want to share a list of images to WhatsApp, however, if I share a single image the code works fine and the image is shared to whatsapp but when sharing multiple images whatsapp shows file format not supported toast message
here is my code

```
  val cachePath = File(requireContext().cacheDir, "images")
                cachePath.mkdirs()
                val uriList = arrayListOf<Uri>()
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    shareClicked.images.forEach {
                        val loader = ImageLoader(requireContext())
                        val request = ImageRequest.Builder(requireContext())
                            .data(
                                it.image
                            )
                            .allowHardware(false)
                            .build()

                        val result = (loader.execute(request) as SuccessResult).drawable
                        val bitmap = (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

                        val UUID = UUID.randomUUID()



                          val stream =
                              FileOutputStream("$cachePath/${UUID}.jpg")
                          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)

                        val newFile = File(cachePath, "$UUID.jpg")
                        val contentUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            requireContext(),
                            "provider",
                            newFile
                        )
                        uriList.add(contentUri)


                    }
```

Comment: Try to share with an email client and other apps.

Comment: `val newFile = File(imagePath, "image.jpg")` That will be the same for every image. Can never work.

Comment: FileOutputStream("$cachePath/${it.image.length}.jpg")

Comment: You have cachePath and imagePath the same. ????

Comment: @blackapps i have fixed it but still getting the same error it works for one image but not for multiple

Comment: But why are you not reacting to ALL my comments?

Comment: @blackapps got into a situation was not able to connect to internet

Comment: `FileOutputStream("$cachePath/${UUID}.jpg")` AND `val newFile = File(cachePath, "$UUID.jpg")`. Why are you building up the same path twice? And why do they look different to me? You dont wanna tell that you have no email client on your device? Or another app with which you can share?

Comment: @blackapps these are the same, fileoutput stream is used to compress and save the bitmap for the second time I am getting the file from cache path

Comment: `Why are you building up the same path twice? ` You did not answer this. Nor my first comment. Sigh..

Comment: @blackapps i have tried sharing into other app did not work, I have updated the code I am not building the same path again now. i have also update the code you can have  a look at it

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable this is what i am getting